# Edit button is not showing in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

The pencil(edit) button is not visible in the region which I have created. Although it was showing before when I created the interactive form. Please let me know if once it goes how can we revoke it back.

Regards,
Anshul Ayushya

Answer (score 0):

While you're editing the Interactive Report page, navigate to its **Attributes**. On the right hand side of the screen, among its properties, you'll see the **Link** section. I guess you removed it, so - set it back.

By default, it shows a  "Link to Custom Target" which is a page in this application. Link icon is, for example, `<img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#e2.gif"  border="0">` - pick one from the list.

Comment: You are correct, the pencil icon appeared after doing the same as per you suggested but I edited after clicking on the button any particular user, then that username is not coming up in next page and also the "Apply Changes" button is also not coming up. Please suggest here.

Comment: You should click the "Target" page and set its **Set items** values correctly (I'd suggest you not to type those values, but select them from the list). As of the "Apply Changes" missing - either it is deleted from the page, or it has the "Server side condition" set to some *condition* that prevents it from being rendered on the page.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. It helped me.
But apply button is still not showing although I have checked server side condition.

Comment: You're welcome. If the "Apply changes" isn't displayed and there's no condition, then I have no idea what's going on.